# Implement ActionResult that just writes the razor _Layout + a const string body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionresult

I'm writing a ReactJs application with jspm and a lot of my views end up looking like this

```
<script>System.import('customers')</script>
```

or

```
<script>System.import('invoicing')</script>
```

so what gets sent to the browser is the `_Layout.cshtml` (as defined by _ViewStart.cshtml`) and that simple body.

Since there's literally no variance here, I'd like to not have to create the view file at all (there's additional reasons for this as well). I'd like to be able to do

```
return new LoadJsModuleResult('customers');
```

or

```
return new LoadJsModuleResult('invoicing');
```

How would I go about writing `LoadJsModuleResult`?

I'm looking at the source for `ViewResult` and `ViewEngineResult` but it seems that at that point everything is already assembled with the assembly happening somewhere in `ViewEngineCollection`. I can track it as far as `BuildManagerWrapper.GetCompiledType` but then we get into the depths of `System.Web`.

Does anyone have any hints?

- I'll note that convenience is not the *only* reason I want to do this, I'm also making a module system that this would work particularly well with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a view LoadJSModule.cshtml in shared containing

```
@model string
<script>System.import('@Model')</script>
```

and then in your controller return `View("LoadJSModule", "modulename")`

You could have a method in a `Controller` subclass all your controllers inherit from

```
public ViewResult LoadJSModule(string modulename) {
   return View("LoadJSModule", modulename);
}
```

so you could return `LoadJSModule("mymodule")`

Comment: That's not a bad idea...so I still have a cshtml somewhere...hmmm. I'd like to see how to do it without writing a file at all, but things seem to be scary there.

Comment: yeah, it aint pretty, but MVC is *built* to return views from controllers. You could probably work around it, but it has little MVC left in it then, and this probably is the most convenient way to do it anyway. You could, but why would you?

Comment: @Martijn this isn't really true though. There is tons of flexibility and customization in MVC. JavascriptResult, ContentResult, etc. Not just views.

Comment: Sure, especially now with the unification of MVC and WebAPI. You could look at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs on how to do a simple custom result type (it's mainly a question of the ExecuteResult method, and setting the right headers), but when you are serving HTML anyway, even if it's bare bones HTML, the machinery is already there. Might as well leverage it.